# Pass an Amended String back into its Original HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a string that is dynamically generated by a plugin and I've changed the format of the date with a regex.

The var that represents the new string shows with the correct formatting in the console, but when I try and pass this back into the innerHTML nothing is happening?

How do I pass the second (reformatted) date string back into the HTML element with the class .date-start, so that the output changes?

Many thanks in advance,

Emily

```js
// remove space in string

var dateStr = document.querySelector(".date-start").innerHTML;

secondDateStr = dateStr.replace(/\sam$/, "am");

dateStr.innerHTML = secondDateStr;

console.log(secondDateStr)
```

```html
<div class="date-start">January 6, 2018 @ 10:00 am</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the posted code, you assign a string (HTMLElement.innerHTML is type of string) to a variable.

Then in `dateStr.innerHTML` what happens is strings in JavaScript are automatically cast to an instance of the String type so here you add a new property to the `dateStr` *object*.

Instead, assign the DOM element to a variable to start with, manipulate your string as needed then assign a new value to the `innerHTML` attribute of the element.

You also want to be sure the selector returns a single element otherwise, if it returns a collection which it does when finds more than one element, you want to get a specific one like `document.querySelector(".date-start")[0]`

```js
// remove space in string

var dateEl = document.querySelector(".date-start");

secondDateStr = dateEl.innerHTML.replace(/\sam$/, "am");

dateEl.innerHTML = secondDateStr;

console.log(secondDateStr)
```

```html
<div class="date-start">January 6, 2018 @ 10:00 am</div>
```

Comment: Lovely thanks Marekful.  In the real world example there are a number of times it shows on the page so i'll be using a forEach loop with .querySelectorAll, but wanted to simplify the code for the example.  Anyway - it all works so thanks very much!